# Use laptop webcam/microphone when RDP'd onto it?

Tags: remote-desktop, webcam, microphone

Scenario: Working from home, so using RDP from my desktop with multi-monitor etc onto my laptop which is sat right next to it on the desk.

When joining video calls I need to end the RDP session and use my laptop directly.

I have seen the inverse of what I'm trying to achieve - if I have a webcam connected to my desktop then I can share that resource and use the webcam as if it was connected to my laptop, but this is slightly different.

I want to use the webcam/microphone from the machine I'm connecting onto, so I can use the laptop built in webcam without having to keep dropping out of my RDP session - is that possible?

Comment: Going by the available sound settings, remote recording is blocked. Probably due to privacy concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Close your RDP connection, open the Connection window again, don't click on Connect, but on the little down-pointing arrow in the bottom left corner to open the Preferences.

Go to the Local Ressources tab, click on Others at the bottom, and check all the right boxes, including Video capture and camera/microphone.

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you - but that does the inverse of what I need. That allows me to share resources already connected to my computer, with my laptop. What I want to do is to use resources on the machine I am connecting to. Not the machine I am connecting from.